# Как можно проверить образуют ли заданные вершины в заданном порядке гамильтонов цикл. с++

Tags: графы

Граф, имеющий n вершин, задан соответствующей матрицей смежности и даны вершины v1, v2, v3,…, vn+1. Напишите программу, которая проверяет, образуют ли вершины в заданном порядке гамильтонов цикл.
Можете написать функцию, которая это проверяет?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: даны вершины v1, v2, v3,…, vn+1. и нужно проверить образуют ли эти вершины в заданном порядке гамильтонов цикл

Comment: @Анастасия какой смысл отвечать боту?) Ему плевать на то, что вы напишите. Даже если вы все объсните подробно, на 40 страниц - он сделает тоже самое)

Answer (score 0):

Если v1 не совпадает с vn+1 - fail.

Если для любой из пар соседей (например v2 и v3) в данном списке не существует ребро в таблице смежности -fail

Для каждой пары пометить первую вершину из пары. Если вершина уже была помечена  - fail.